# Returning Values from a geolocation API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, geolocation

I am trying to return the longitude and latitude of the user from the geolocation api but so far i keep getting errors when i try to use them outside the function.

I have tried using the values within the function and they work but i cannot seem to get them to work outside the position function. I need a way to make the "location" object accessible to other functions.

```
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    const location = {
      lat:position.coords.latitude,
      long:position.coords.longitude
    }
    return location
  },
  (err)=>console.log(err),

);
console.log(location)
```

I expect to get the code inside the "location" object located within the position function.Please Help

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, and `location` variable is only defined inside the getCurrentPosition callback ...

Comment: `location` variable doesn't exists in that scope, you should pass a callback function to `getCurrentPosition` to always access the latest value.

Check this live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/geolocation-callback-81oj7
And also check MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Getting_the_current_position

Answer (score 0):

The `HTML5` API getcurrentPosition is assync, the easiest way to use the location, is to use a callback function, like this:

```
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    const location = {
      lat:position.coords.latitude,
      long:position.coords.longitude
    }
    showLocation(location); // <- Function that will use location data
  },
  (err)=>console.log(err),

);
function showLocation(location) {
    console.log(location);
    //other stuff    
}
```

this link can help to understand better:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your function inside a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and wait for it to resolve. This way you can extract the values whenever they become available using the `then` method. It is kind of similar to adding a callback but it works differently.

So the code below here does not execute here on SO for security reasons, but it will in your own file.

The `Promise` can take a callback function with **2** parameters. `resolve` and `reject`.

`resolve` could be seen as something like `return`. But instead of returning the value it stores it in the `Promise` and changed the state of the `Promise` to `resolved`. When that happens all adjecent `then` methods will be called.

`reject` is when an error occurs or you simply don't want the `Promise` to `resolve`. It calls the adjecent `catch` block after the `Promise` statement.

In the `then` and `catch` blocks you can access your `resolved` or `rejected` values.

Check out more examples in this [Medium article](https://medium.com/bithubph/creating-a-promise-wrapper-for-old-callback-api-methods-fa1b03b82a90).

```js
/**
 * Wrap function in a Promise.
 * Resolve when position is found.
 * Reject when error occurs.
 */
const getLocation = () => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) => {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const location = {
          lat:position.coords.latitude,
          long:position.coords.longitude
        };
        resolve(location); // Resolve with location. location can now be accessed in the .then method.
      },
      err => reject(err) // Reject with err. err can now be accessed in the .catch method.
    );
  }
);

/**
 * then is called when the Promise is resolved
 * catch is called when the Promise rejects or encounters an error.
 */
getLocation()
    .then(location => console.log(location))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```