# How to set a variable using geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: geolocation, javascript-scope

This is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544564/how-geolocation-getcurrentposition-return-value), but different in that I am trying to understand why I cannot set an outside variable from inside of geolocation.getCurrentPosition

I can't seem to get any kind of return value from it, and I can't set a value from it. I can only access the position object from inside of it. I have tried passing in `this`.

I forked derek-朕會功夫's fiddle and modified it:
https://jsfiddle.net/TwoFistedJustice/c3qr29L7/1/

Here is another fiddle based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829690/returning-values-from-a-geolocation-api):

https://jsfiddle.net/TwoFistedJustice/yu8Lzjvx/4/

I'm very perplexed.

Could someone please help me to:

1. Understand what is going on behind the scenes to make it behave it
   this way.
2. Understand how to set a variable in an outer scope from inside
   getCurrentPosition().

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading up on the call stack and callback queue. And I gather that the behavior that has been perplexing me has to do with how Javascript handles the various stacks and queues. [This piece by Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) helps to clear it up, though it is bit much to absorb all at once.

If I add a setTimeout with any delay value, even 0, foo is USUALLY changed. With near-zero values, it varies a bit.

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log('SetTimeout\n -  Foo only changes if this goes AFTER the Promise\n foo:', foo)}
```

, 0);

This is a fiddle  derived from the others that more clearly shows what is going on. [https://jsfiddle.net/TwoFistedJustice/arkqb0x8/71/](https://jsfiddle.net/TwoFistedJustice/arkqb0x8/70/)